# Testing Elastic Beanstalk Website

Tags: amazon-web-services, testing, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have setup a website with elastic beanstalk on Amazon and i would like to test how many hits it can manage before it fails.

I would like to see it auto scaling the load balancers kicking in etc..

What software can i use to run the tests as i would like to see what it can handle so i can tell my client.

```
New application version was deployed to running EC2 instances.
```

I have taken a look at some applications for benchmarking but cannot seems to find anything that runs the tests i am after there is obviously something out there that i dont know about yet.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this question isn't about programming, so it's more suitable to stackexchange.
Here's a similar thread that can answer your question:
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/128304/is-there-any-way-to-test-how-will-the-site-perform-under-load